# Relay access denied, but only for some domain recipients

Tags: postfix

we have a website with a SMTP server (Postfix) we used for almost a year.
From about yesterday we keep getting the following error when sending emails to hotmail destinations:

```
Feb 12 10:52:34 CentOS-60-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[1975]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from sportilia.com[46.4.1.2]: 554 5.7.1 <removed_address@hotmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<no-reply@sportilia.com> to=<remove_address@hotmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<www.sportilia.com>
```

I'd like to highlight that we successfully sent email to hotmail addresses since yesterday, but now, without we changed anything on our postfix server, we keep getting this error. I also want to say that we successfully send emails to other domains (e.g. gmail.com).

Any idea on what could be causing this issue? There could be some configuration we could tune to fix it or at least investigate about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file and/or your script.

`mynetworks` probably contains only `127.0.0.0/8`.

And you tried to connect from your external ip 46.4.1.2 `"RCPT from sportilia.com[46.4.1.2]"`.

Changing connection string to `127.0.0.1` probably changed your source IP also to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: You're right, we have only 127.0.0.0/8. And probably this is the reason why it's working now. But I still wonder why the old connection string did work until yesterday..

Comment: Something was changed in your script or in your server configuration. It could be dns or /etc/hosts if you use hostname in your script. Also it could be a change in one of the components/programs you use in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP is listed on at least one blacklist (see [this](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check)) and it's possible that Hotmail considers this reason enough to block you outright.

Comment: We checked on the service you provided, and there is only one blacklist that lists us (apews.org), which apparently created an entry for our IP on march 2012. According to yot link, it seems that this blacklist service (apews) is not that much reliable.. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

SMTP Code 554. 5.7.1 is basically a rejection from the Recipient Domain

Cause
IP has been included in a Real-Time Blacklist due to there is Spam coming from your Domain.
You Domain/IP has been blacklisted by the recipient.

Check the standard recommendations at: http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

We solved by changing on the email sending scripts the connection string to the SMTP to: 127.0.0.1.
I can't explain exactly why, by the way. But it works.